# php artisan migrate foreign key error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, artisan-migrate

**Master table POll**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('poll', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('poll_question', 255);
            $table->boolean('status',1)->default(0)->index();
            $table->unsignedInteger('order');
        });
    }
```

**Detail table**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('poll_option', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('poll_id');
            $table->string('poll_option', 255);
            $table->unsignedInteger('vote_poll_option');
            $table->unsignedInteger('order');
            $table->boolean('status',1)->default(0)->index();

            $table->foreign('poll_id')->references('id')->on('poll')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

When I run php artisan with foreign key

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mydb`.`#sql-6f4_433` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Note: I m using **laravel 5.2** and mysql type already Innodb What is main causes to incorrectly formed

Comment: May $table->integer('poll_id')->unsigned();

Comment: or $table->unsignedInteger('poll_id')

Answer (score 0):

in Details table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('poll_option', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('poll_id')->unsigned(); //Change Here
            $table->string('poll_option', 255);
            $table->unsignedInteger('vote_poll_option');
            $table->unsignedInteger('order');
            $table->boolean('status',1)->default(0)->index();

            $table->foreign('poll_id')
              ->references('id')->on('poll')
              ->onDelete('CASCADE')
              ->onUpdate('CASCADE');
        });
    }
```

this will work for you

Comment: Thank you Bindesh. I missed "->unsigned()" in foreign key field.